# How to correctly add the last index value from another df to an empty df? Pandas related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, debugging, typeerror, keyerror

Say I have the following empty df named `df_pnl`, after being called it produces the following output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [PnL, Type of Trade, ROI, Cumulative ROI, Cumulative Investment]
Index: []
```

If you run `df_pnl.index[-1:]`, it produces the following output:

```
Index([], dtype='object', name='End Date')
```

Now, there's another df called `df_chosen_trading_pair` which shows the following data as output when called:

```
                         Close Price 
End Date                             
2022-06-25 02:29:59.999        11.21
2022-06-25 02:59:59.999        11.19
2022-06-25 03:29:59.999        11.25
2022-06-25 03:59:59.999        11.37
2022-06-25 04:29:59.999        11.34
                             ...    
2022-06-27 04:59:59.999        10.96
2022-06-27 05:29:59.999        10.80
2022-06-27 05:59:59.999        10.82
2022-06-27 06:29:59.999        10.84
2022-06-27 06:59:59.999        10.88

[106 rows x 1 columns]
```

If you run `df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1]`, it produces the following output:

```
'2022-06-27 06:59:59.999'
```

If you run `type(df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1])`, it produces the following output:

```
str
```

I need to add the value of `df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1]` to `df_pnl.index[-1:]` so I end up getting the following output when calling `df_pnl`:

```
                         PnL   Type of Trade  ROI  Cumulative ROI  Cumulative Investment
End Date                             
2022-06-27 06:59:59.999  NaN             NaN  NaN             NaN                    NaN
```

I tried the following lines and none of them worked:

> **In[124]:** `df_pnl.index[0:] = df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1]`

> TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations

> **In[125]:** `df_pnl["End Date"][-1] = df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1]`

> KeyError: 'End Date'

May I get some assistance here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I ended up getting the solution I was looking for by accident, the following line:

> **In [167]:** `df_pnl.loc[df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1], :] = None`

Throws:

```
                         PnL   Type of Trade  ROI  Cumulative ROI  Cumulative Investment
End Date                             
2022-06-27 06:59:59.999  NaN             NaN  NaN             NaN                    NaN
```

Besides, I realized that if I want to add a new row to `df_pnl` with the same logic,  I just have to change the internal value within the array, like this:

> **In [167]:** `df_pnl.loc[df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-2], :] = None`

Throws:

```
                         PnL   Type of Trade  ROI  Cumulative ROI  Cumulative Investment
End Date                             
2022-06-27 06:59:59.999  NaN             NaN  NaN             NaN                    NaN

2022-06-27 06:29:59.999  NaN             NaN  NaN             NaN                    NaN
```